# Iteration over columns in Matrix using piping

Tags: f#, linear-algebra, mathnet-numerics

I'm trying to divide matrix by its last row (each column by its last element - aka Homogeneous coordinates) and then return submatrix containing everything except that last row.
Something like this in Matlab:

```
normx = bsxfun(@rdivide,A,A(end,:));
output = normx(1:end-1,:);
```

Since I'm new to F# I'm not quite sure about anything, but I tried this:

```
let hnorm(A:Matrix<double>) = 
    let partialResult = A |> Matrix.iterCols (fun col -> col/col.[col.Count-1])
    partialResult.Rows(0,3)
```

but I got the "*This expression was expected to have type 'unit' but here has type 'Vector< double >'*" error in the lambda expression.

And I don't understand what is wrong since examples like

```
let result = [2;4;6] |> List.map (fun x -> x * x * x)
```

work well.

Could someone please explain how this can be done because I think I'm missing some basics or misunderstood them.

Thanks!

Comment: use `mapCols`.  In F# there is a convention `iterXXX` functions are used for side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the signature of `Matrix.iterCols` (hover on it in your IDE), you'll see that the argument it takes is a function `Vector<'a> -> unit` - that is, it's a function that takes a `Vector<'a>` as argument and returns a `unit`.

Your function `fun col -> col/col.[col.Count-1]`, on the other hand, actually returns a `Vector<_>`, because that's the result of division there. Since `Vector<_>` is not a `unit`, the compiler complains: *"this value was expected to have type 'unit', but here has type Vector<>"*. This is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

As a matter of F# convention, functions named `iter*` usually mean *"go over this sequence and produce some side-effect for every element"*, where side-effect might be something like printing to the screen or modifying a memory cell, etc. This is why the argument of `iterCols` is expected to return `unit`: its sole purpose is to produce a side-effect, it shouldn't return any useful values.

But what you're trying to do is *not* to produce a side-effect. What you're trying to do is to create another `Matrix`, which would have all its columns divided by their last element. This operation of transforming a container by applying some function to each of its elements is traditionally called "map" in functional programming. And lo: there is actually a function [`Matrix.mapCols`](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/FSharp/LinearAlgebra.Matrix.fs#L255), which does exactly what you expect:

```
let partialResult = A |> Matrix.mapCols (fun idx col -> col/col.[col.Count-1])
```

Note that the argument of `mapCols` should take two parameters instead of one: the first is the column index, and the second is the column itself.

Comment: Thanks! That's it. Additional question, since I'm supposed to write `idx` which I won't use, is there some _omit_ symbol like`~` in Matlab? Maybe smth like `fun _ col -> col/col.[col.Count-1]`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the syntax. You can use underscore for variable that you don't care about